# Get errors when using certain versions of spring boot cloud and spring boot. How can I know which versions go together?

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, spring-cloud

Is there something in Maven that will tell me that if I'm using version 1.5.4 of `spring-boot` then I need at least version `Camden.SRX` for `spring-cloud-starter-parent`?

I was getting non-helpful errors that a class was not found as I was using Spring 1.5.4 and Brixton for cloud.

Is there a way to use Maven to find matching/compatible versions?

Comment: Go to [Spring Cloud's home page](http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/) and scroll down to the *Release Trains* section and ...

Comment: There's not a way in maven currently